# Schengen Visa Refusal Article 2 (21)

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-rejections

i applied with my parents to Germany. my dad got the visa while me and mum got the following: One or more member states are of the believe that you are a threat to the public order, the internal security, public health according to Arrocle 2 No 21 of the Resolution (EC) Nr. 2016/ 399 (Schengen Border Kodex) or to the international relations of one or more member states.

Any idea what that is or if it allows me to reapply? we always received Schengen visa together.

Comment: Have you ever traveled to Schengen before?

Comment: Just a reminder from me that the answer to the other question is blatantly wrong. Since this comes up regularly, it would have been a great addition if someone with more knowledge than me would write a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **One or more member state(s) consider you to be a threat to public policy, internal security, pub
>   lic health as defined in Article 2(19) of Regulation (EC) No 562/2006 (Schengen Borders Code) or
>   the international relations of one or more of the member states).**
>
> • You have submitted fake or false documents and / or made contradictory statements.
>
> • You have attempted deceit.
>
> • You have a negative entry in the AZR (Central Register of Foreigners); as long as this remains, it is
>   usually not possible to grant you a visa.

https://accra.diplo.de/blob/1120620/1c3be7eadcc793be49d586d77787604c/schengen-visa-refusal-data.pdf

Perhaps you should ask the consulate for clarification.